# Redirect Current page to https if video src in the page is https

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I have multiple streams with `http://` and `https://` protocols, my webpage is working on both but if my stream is `https://` I have issues to play it in a `http://` web page.  I want to redirect to `https://` if stream is `https` and redirect to `http://` if the stream is `http` too.

I'm just a beginner I tried some code but no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {`var val = $("#my_video_1_html5_api").find('source').attr("src");`if (val && !val.match(/^http([s]?):\/\/.*/)) {
location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");`}`});
```

When I tried `if (val && !val.match(/^https:\/\/.*/))` my web page keeps reloading.

Comment: You'll also have to check `location.href` to see if it uses the same protocol as the video URL and don't change it in those cases.

Comment: i'm stuck on the first issue for now i didn't think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also have to check `location.href` to see if it uses the same protocol as the video URL and don't change it in those cases.

Here is an example:

```
var val = $("#my_video_1_html5_api").find('source').attr("src");
var videoProtocol = val.match(/^http(s?):/)[0];
if (!location.href.startsWith(videoProtocol)) {
  location.href = location.href.replace(/^http(s?):/, videoProtocol);
}
```